# How to configure Apache web server to be able to write file in Ubuntu root folder

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

What I am trying to do is to create a folder from PHP code. Initially it may sound like a PHP question, but after sending lot of time online, I realize that the main issue is related to Apache permission. I tried almost everything that I could google but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I installed the Apache server with apt-get and with the default installation web root was /var/www/html and my PHP script is there. With default installation I was not even able to write file in that folder as well. Later from google, I found that I have to make www-data the owner of the folder where I am trying to write file. I did so and the folder got created.

But my main goal is to create the folder under /root/work/temp but if I follow the same process and make www-data the owner of that folder like I did for /var/www/html, it do not work.

So what do I need to different in this case. FYI, I have also applied chmod to make both folder have enough read/write permission.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are creating severe security issues by allowing your web software to write to directories used by root. You need to re-think your implementation so that it is safe.

Comment: Why I need is because I am doing a temporary implementation where security is not a concern. I am needing this because of a 3rd party software which is made in such a way that it only works when installed in the root. Or you can say it just by default installs there and I do not have way to change it unless I change the code. But I do not want that at this point. And this is a disposable installation. I do not have other vendor to try for this software which is a special need. So I must create some files in the temp folder for the software to process my data.

Comment: Then you should use a chroot environment for this software only. You can use `makejail` software to create these chroot jails, and then assign your PHP-FPM child pools to run in this chroot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache also needs to be be to traverse the path *to* `/root/work/temp` so check the permissions for `/root` and `/root/work`, they both need to be at least executable by the user Apache runs as.

However the main question I would have is `why on earth would you want to do this in the first place!`

You may also need to allow this to happen in SELinux (or similar) if you are running them.

Comment: Thanks. Why I need is because I am doing a temporary implementation where security is not a concern. I am needing this because of a 3rd party software which is made in such a way that it only works when installed in the root. Or you can say it just by default installs there and I do not have way to change it unless I change the code. But I do not want that at this point. And this is a disposable installation. I do not have other vendor to try for this software which is a special need. So I must create some files in the temp folder for the software to process my data.

Comment: Thanks it worked after I assigned permission to /root and /root/work. I will figure out how to make things secure when I complete my experiment.